# Custom angular directive to add/remove class in an interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created my own angular directive which will add and remove a class based off of a condition passed into it like below:

```
app.directive("alerter", function ($interval, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            var loginExpired = attrs.alerter;
            var addClassInterval = undefined;
            var timer = 3000;
            var className = "alert";

            addClassInterval = $interval(addClass, timer);

            function addClass() {
                if (elem.hasClass(className)) {
                    elem.removeClass(className);
                } else if (loginExpired) {
                    elem.addClass(className);
                }

                $compile(elem)($scope);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This can then be used on an element as an attribute like below:

```
<div alerter="{{model.loginTime > model.expiryTime}}"> ... </div>
```

However, even when alerter evaluates to false, it still adds the class, but I'm not sure why? Also the `$interval` seems to not be working as intended, here is a Plunker I've created to demonstrate:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YKb6YARLaBnsevuoxv3G?p=preview

Thanks!

### Edit

When I remove `$compile(elem)($scope);` it fixes the issue I was having with `$interval` however, I know that one of the conditions passed in is always `false` but it still applies the class to it

Comment: Does it work as you'd expect when you comment out `$compile(elem)($scope);`

Comment: Remove `$compile(elem)($scope);`

Comment: I've just tried that and sort of.. but they both change together, 1 of the items passed in is `false` so it should never change

Comment: you should investigate ng-class directive angular already provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to parse the values via `attr` you will need to parse the value of `attr.alerter` as it is coming in a string (not a boolean)

you can use this code to do this:

```
var loginExpired = $parse(attrs.alerter)();
```

Note: you will need to inject in the `$parse` service

Another (less optimal solution) is to just do a string comparison of `attrs.alerter === 'true'`

Answer (score 1):

```
var loginExpired = attrs.alerter;
```

this will always be true because you are getting the attribute value which is "true" or "false" both not empty strings  hence always truthy if you want to use attrs and not an isolated scope  then you'll have to check something like

```
var loginExpired = /true/.test(attrs.alerter);
```